# PHP image resize getting name and path

Tags: php, image, uploadify

I am trying to figure out where its putting the new resized image here.

```
function createFile($output_filename = null,$imageNewName) {
        if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
            imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$imageNewName.'.'.$this->ext, $this->quality);
        } elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
            imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$imageNewName.'.'.$this->ext);
        } elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
            imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$imageNewName.'.'.$this->ext);
        }
        $this->output = $this->uploaddir. $imageNewName;

        echo $this->uploaddir. $imageNewName .'.'.$this->ext;
}

function resize($newWidth, $newHeight) {
    $width = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $height = imagesy($this->img_r);

    $newWidth = $newWidth;
    $newHeight = $newHeight;

    $this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($this->dst_r, $this->img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    $this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
    $this->img_h = $newHeight;
    $this->img_w = $newWidth;
}

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/img/nonfb/';

$fileNameBase  = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($fileNameBase, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);   
$fileNameNEW = $imageNewName . '.' . $extension;

$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $fileNameNEW;
echo 'TARGET=' . $targetFile;

move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

$image = new Image();
$image->setFile($targetFile);
$image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
$image->resize(50,50);
$image->createFile(md5($tempFile,$fileNameNEW));
$image->flush()
```

I can tell its taking the dst_r as the current image and img_r as the resource image but im not sure how to use **echo** on those to find out their values. What i am trying to do is find out where its placing that resized image so i can rename it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: dst_r/img_r's values are useless. they'll simply be GD resource handles and meaningless outside of the context of the currently executing script.

Comment: $_REQUEST['folder'] Doesn't look very safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this code resides in a class. As in line 9 of the `createFile` function, the file will probably reside at this path:

```
echo $this->uploaddir. $imageNewName .'.'.$this->ext;
```

Comment: Alright i changed it but i keep getting the same error. Check my OP.

Comment: it seems as the line before the last line is wrong: `$image->createFile(md5($tempFile,$fileNameNEW));` should probably be `$image->createFile(md5($tempFile),$fileNameNEW);`. notice the parenthesis.

Comment: Alright i made that correction and its now passing the name.. and it seems to now be placing the image in the correct name schema... How about that last error? Check updated OP.